# perl Curses and unicode: why addstr prints fine whereas addstring prints garbage?

Tags: perl, unicode, curses

`addstr` — code, output:

```
use Curses;
initscr;
addstr 0, 0, 'Ж 会 र';
addstr 1, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";
getch;
endwin;
```

```
Ж 会 र
Curses 1.43, perl v5.36.0, OS: openbsd
```

`addstring` — code, output:

```
use Curses;
initscr;
addstring 0, 0, 'Ж 会 र';
addstring 1, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";
getchar;
endwin;
```

```
Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
Curses 1.43, perl v5.36.0, OS: openbsd
```

Why is this behavior observed?
Shouldn't it be vice versa, since `addstr` is legacy  whereas `addstring` is meant to be supportive of unicode?

https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses#Wide-Character-Aware-Functions
https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses#Available-Wide-Character-Aware-Functions

---

## Update:

Wider example, with unicode string:

- hardcoded,
- taken from a variable
- passed as a CLI argument
- read from a file via backticks
- read from a file via `open`

We need a file with unicode string:

```
echo -n 'Ж 会 र' > unicode.string.txt
```

---

#### Case 1: `addstr`, no additional declarations:

```
use Curses;

my $unicode_string_variable  = 'Ж 会 र';
my $unicode_string_argv      = $ARGV[0];
my $unicode_string_backticks = `cat unicode.string.txt`;
open my $open_pipe_read_handle, '-|', 'cat', 'unicode.string.txt' || die;
my $unicode_string_open_pipe = <$open_pipe_read_handle>;

# print unicode to files
open my $hardcoded_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.hardcoded' || die;
  print $hardcoded_handle 'Ж 会 र';
  close $hardcoded_handle;
open my  $variable_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.variable'  || die;
  print  $variable_handle $unicode_string_variable;
  close  $variable_handle;
open my      $argv_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.argv'      || die;
  print      $argv_handle $unicode_string_argv;
  close      $argv_handle;
open my $backticks_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.backticks' || die;
  print $backticks_handle $unicode_string_backticks;
  close $backticks_handle;
open my $open_pipe_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.open_pipe' || die;
  print $open_pipe_handle $unicode_string_open_pipe;
  close $open_pipe_handle;

# print unicode to STDOUT
printf "%s: %s\n", 'hardcoded', 'Ж 会 र';
printf "%s: %s\n", 'variable ', $unicode_string_variable;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'argv     ', $unicode_string_argv;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'backticks', $unicode_string_backticks;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'open_pipe', $unicode_string_open_pipe;

initscr;

# print unicode to Curses
addstr 0, 0, 'hardcoded: ' . 'Ж 会 र';
addstr 1, 0, 'variable : ' . $unicode_string_variable;
addstr 2, 0, 'argv     : ' . $unicode_string_argv;
addstr 3, 0, 'backticks: ' . $unicode_string_backticks;
addstr 4, 0, 'open_pipe: ' . $unicode_string_open_pipe;

addstr 5, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";

getchar;
endwin;
```

run:

```
perl curses-unicode.addstr.pl 'Ж 会 र'
```

Curses output, **all-working** unicode:

```
hardcoded: Ж 会 र
variable : Ж 会 र
argv     : Ж 会 र
backticks: Ж 会 र
open_pipe: Ж 会 र
Curses 1.43, perl v5.36.0, OS: openbsd
```

STDOUT output, **all-working** unicode:

```
hardcoded: Ж 会 र
variable : Ж 会 र
argv     : Ж 会 र
backticks: Ж 会 र
open_pipe: Ж 会 र
```

Files output, **all-working** unicode:

```
cat unicode.string.*
Ж 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 र
```

---

#### Case 2: `addstring`, no additional declarations:

```
use Curses;

my $unicode_string_variable  = 'Ж 会 र';
my $unicode_string_argv      = $ARGV[0];
my $unicode_string_backticks = `cat unicode.string.txt`;
open my $open_pipe_read_handle, '-|', 'cat', 'unicode.string.txt' || die;
my $unicode_string_open_pipe = <$open_pipe_read_handle>;

# print unicode to files
open my $hardcoded_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.hardcoded' || die;
  print $hardcoded_handle 'Ж 会 र';
  close $hardcoded_handle;
open my  $variable_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.variable'  || die;
  print  $variable_handle $unicode_string_variable;
  close  $variable_handle;
open my      $argv_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.argv'      || die;
  print      $argv_handle $unicode_string_argv;
  close      $argv_handle;
open my $backticks_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.backticks' || die;
  print $backticks_handle $unicode_string_backticks;
  close $backticks_handle;
open my $open_pipe_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.open_pipe' || die;
  print $open_pipe_handle $unicode_string_open_pipe;
  close $open_pipe_handle;

# print unicode to STDOUT
printf "%s: %s\n", 'hardcoded', 'Ж 会 र';
printf "%s: %s\n", 'variable ', $unicode_string_variable;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'argv     ', $unicode_string_argv;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'backticks', $unicode_string_backticks;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'open_pipe', $unicode_string_open_pipe;

initscr;

# print unicode to Curses
addstring 0, 0, 'hardcoded: ' . 'Ж 会 र';
addstring 1, 0, 'variable : ' . $unicode_string_variable;
addstring 2, 0, 'argv     : ' . $unicode_string_argv;
addstring 3, 0, 'backticks: ' . $unicode_string_backticks;
addstring 4, 0, 'open_pipe: ' . $unicode_string_open_pipe;

addstring 5, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";

getchar;
endwin;
```

run:

```
perl curses-unicode.addstring.pl 'Ж 会 र'
```

Curses output, **all-broken** unicode::

```
hardcoded: Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
variable : Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
argv     : Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
backticks: Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
open_pipe: Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
Curses 1.43, perl v5.36.0, OS: openbsd
```

STDOUT output, **all-working** unicode::

```
hardcoded: Ж 会 र
variable : Ж 会 र
argv     : Ж 会 र
backticks: Ж 会 र
open_pipe: Ж 会 र
```

Files output, **all-working** unicode:

```
cat unicode.string.*
Ж 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 र
```

---

#### Case 3: `addstring`, additional declarations `use utf8`, `-CA` and `:encoding(UTF-8)`:

```
use utf8;
use Curses;

my $unicode_string_variable  = 'Ж 会 र';
my $unicode_string_argv      = $ARGV[0];
my $unicode_string_backticks = `cat unicode.string.txt`;
open my $open_pipe_read_handle, '-|:encoding(UTF-8)', 'cat', 'unicode.string.txt' || die;
my $unicode_string_open_pipe = <$open_pipe_read_handle>;

# print unicode to files
open my $hardcoded_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.hardcoded' || die;
  print $hardcoded_handle 'Ж 会 र';
  close $hardcoded_handle;
open my  $variable_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.variable'  || die;
  print  $variable_handle $unicode_string_variable;
  close  $variable_handle;
open my      $argv_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.argv'      || die;
  print      $argv_handle $unicode_string_argv;
  close      $argv_handle;
open my $backticks_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.backticks' || die;
  print $backticks_handle $unicode_string_backticks;
  close $backticks_handle;
open my $open_pipe_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.open_pipe' || die;
  print $open_pipe_handle $unicode_string_open_pipe;
  close $open_pipe_handle;

# print unicode to STDOUT
printf "%s: %s\n", 'hardcoded', 'Ж 会 र';
printf "%s: %s\n", 'variable ', $unicode_string_variable;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'argv     ', $unicode_string_argv;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'backticks', $unicode_string_backticks;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'open_pipe', $unicode_string_open_pipe;

initscr;

# print unicode to Curses
addstring 0, 0, 'hardcoded: ' . 'Ж 会 र';
addstring 1, 0, 'variable : ' . $unicode_string_variable;
addstring 2, 0, 'argv     : ' . $unicode_string_argv;
addstring 3, 0, 'backticks: ' . $unicode_string_backticks;
addstring 4, 0, 'open_pipe: ' . $unicode_string_open_pipe;

addstring 5, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";

getchar;
endwin;
```

run:

```
perl -CA curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl 'Ж 会 र'
```

Curses output, **partially-working, partially-broken** unicode::

```
hardcoded: Ж 会 र
variable : Ж 会 र
argv     : Ж 会 र
backticks: Ð~V ä¼~Z à¤°
open_pipe: Ж 会 र
Curses 1.43, perl v5.36.0, OS: openbsd
```

STDOUT&STDERR output, **all-working** unicode:

```
Wide character in print at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 12, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
Wide character in print at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 15, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
Wide character in print at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 18, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
Wide character in print at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 24, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
Wide character in printf at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 28, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
hardcoded: Ж 会 र
Wide character in printf at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 29, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
variable : Ж 会 र
Wide character in printf at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 30, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
argv     : Ж 会 र
backticks: Ж 会 र
Wide character in printf at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line 32, <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.
open_pipe: Ж 会 र
```

Files output, **all-working** unicode:

```
cat unicode.string.*
Ж 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 रЖ 会 र
```

---

- Why unicode just works for `STDOUT` and writing to files in all 3 cases without any hassle, whereas `Curses` balks? What is so special to `Curses`? Isn't it a bug of some kind in `Curses` given that with `STDOUT` and files all OK?
- Is there a single place to enable unicode or need you to specify separately; where is uniformity; why?:

  - `use utf8` for unicode in the source;
  - `-CA` for cli arguments;
  - `:encoding(UTF-8)` for `open`
- How to fix unicode for backticks?
- What are `Wide character in print at curses-unicode.addstring.utf8,CA,encodingUTF8.pl line ..., <$open_pipe_read_handle> line 1.` on `STDERR` and how to rid of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `use utf8;` pragma:

```
use utf8;
use Curses;
initscr;
addstring 0, 0, 'Ж 会 र';
addstring 1, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";
getch;
endwin;
```

Output:

```
Ж 会 र
Curses 1.43, perl v5.34.0, OS: linux
```

See the [Perl Unicode FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq#Can-I-use-Unicode-in-my-Perl-sources?). Why the `addstr` version does work is probably a matter of luck (on my system only the third character is correctly displayed).

If you want to handle command line arguments from `$ARGV` as utf8 then you need a different approach. One way is to call Perl explicitly with the `-C` flag set to `A` or `32` (this is a special setting that controls the `$ARGV` encoding) or equivalently by setting the `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable in the terminal to A.

Alternatively you can re-encode `$ARGV` from within the code:

```
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
@ARGV = map { decode_utf8($_, 1) } @ARGV;
```

In this case you don't need the command line flag.

This alternative also works for backticks substitution:

```
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
my $unicode_string_backticks = decode_utf8(`cat unicode.string.txt`, 1);
```

Source: https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicookbook-decode-argv-as-utf8.html/

---

There is however a simpler solution that sets utf8 for hardcoded strings, argv, filehandles, printf, backticks etc. simultaneously, which is the `utf8::all` module. With this you don't need command line flags or the `Encode` module.- Because it targets STDOUT the warnings about wide characters are resolved as well.

```
use utf8::all;
use Curses;

my $unicode_string_variable  = 'Ж 会 र';
my $unicode_string_argv      = $ARGV[0];
#my $unicode_string_backticks = decode_utf8(`cat unicode.string.txt`,1);
my $unicode_string_backticks = `cat unicode.string.txt`;
open my $open_pipe_read_handle, '-|:encoding(UTF-8)', 'cat', 'unicode.string.txt' || die;
my $unicode_string_open_pipe = <$open_pipe_read_handle>;

# print unicode to files
open my $hardcoded_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.hardcoded' || die;
  print $hardcoded_handle 'Ж 会 र';
  close $hardcoded_handle;
open my  $variable_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.variable'  || die;
  print  $variable_handle $unicode_string_variable;
  close  $variable_handle;
open my      $argv_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.argv'      || die;
  print      $argv_handle $unicode_string_argv;
  close      $argv_handle;
open my $backticks_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.backticks' || die;
  print $backticks_handle $unicode_string_backticks;
  close $backticks_handle;
open my $open_pipe_handle, '>', 'unicode.string.open_pipe' || die;
  print $open_pipe_handle $unicode_string_open_pipe;
  close $open_pipe_handle;

# print unicode to STDOUT
printf "%s: %s\n", 'hardcoded', 'Ж 会 र';
printf "%s: %s\n", 'variable ', $unicode_string_variable;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'argv     ', $unicode_string_argv;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'backticks', $unicode_string_backticks;
printf "%s: %s\n", 'open_pipe', $unicode_string_open_pipe;

initscr;

# print unicode to Curses
addstring 0, 0, 'hardcoded: ' . 'Ж 会 र';
addstring 1, 0, 'variable : ' . $unicode_string_variable;
addstring 2, 0, 'argv     : ' . $unicode_string_argv;
addstring 3, 0, 'backticks: ' . $unicode_string_backticks;
addstring 4, 0, 'open_pipe: ' . $unicode_string_open_pipe;

addstring 5, 0, 'Curses ' . Curses->VERSION . ", perl $^V" . ", OS: $^O";

getchar;
endwin;
```

Source: https://blog.ostermiller.org/perl-wide-character-in-print/

If for whatever reason you can't or don't want to install this module then `use utf8;` together with the command line flags `-CSDA` also resolves all issues. Note that with these command line flags you should *not* use `decode_utf8()` in your code.

Comment: Semi-yes. This given snippet now works correctly, but put `addstring 0, 0, $ARGV[0];` instead of `addstring 0, 0, 'Ж 会 र';`, then call it `perl curses.unicode.pl 'Ж 会 र'` and garbage reappears

Comment: @uxer for that use `perl -CA curses.unicode.pl 'Ж 会 र'`.

Comment: Good to know. Step further: we receive our unicode string via backticks or `open`. The latter seems to need `:encoding(UTF-8)`. How to fix backticks? Why you need 3 different places — `use utf8`, `-CA`, `:encoding(UTF-8)` — to enable the same darned unicode? Where is uniformity? Why only `Curses` requires it, whereas `STDOUT` and writing to files work out-of-the-box? I also get errors `Wide character in print...` I have updated the question

Comment: @uxer see edits for a backticks version and a single solution for all issues.